# Excluding duplicate values based on one or more other columns, rather than an entire row

Tags: sql

I need to remove duplicate total values from the results of a complicated SQL query that produces a table of invoice details.

I've looked for examples, but i can't find anything that allows me to remove duplicates in just one column, based on the values in one other column.

This is a basic example of the data i have. I need to maintain this table format:

```
Project     Section     Reference     Section_Amount     Total
a           1           inv1          1500               1500
a           1           inv2          1000               3000
a           2           inv2          1000               3000
a           3           inv2          1000               3000
a           4           inv3          1700               1700
```

I need to have:

```
Project     Section     Reference     Section_Amount     Total
a           1           inv1          1500               1500
a           1           inv2          1000               3000
a           2           inv2          1000               NULL
a           3           inv2          1000               NULL
a           4           inv3          1700               1700
```

As you can see the total for invoice 2 is only shown once.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select Project, Section, Reference, Section_Amount,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by reference order by section) = 1
             then total
        end) as total
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Can i use something similar to split the invoice total evenly over each section? e.g. 1000 each for sections 1, 2 and 3 that relate to inv2?

Comment: @M.Jones . . . You would use `total / count(*) over (partition by reference)`.